# How to remotely install an android application on a android phone connected to the same network?

Tags: android, remote-access

I had an idea for a project in which I want to remotely install an apk on an android user's mobile connected to the same network as me...Is this possible?

Comment: Can this user's phone be "prepared", by rooting and installing another app? Or just somebody innocent, and unaware walking by and you install random APK's?

Comment: Can this be done without rooting?

Comment: Only if you have an USB connection to the device.

Comment: I want it to be remote...can I integrate it with another app in which when the user is installing the app, the apk would be installed silently?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

No, for obvious security reasons.